# String as member of container which is a member of a C++ class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have a class that has a `set` member variable. This set is going to hold a bunch of `std::string`s which are added to it throughout the life of the object.

The strings are passed in from a calling function (they are created in the calling function). My understanding is that in C++ `string` objects have their destructors called as soon as they leave scope. So if I understand correctly, when the calling method which created the string exits scope, the destructor should be called. Likewise, even if I make a copy of the string in the method in my class, it would still be destroyed when out of scope. However, I want the string to live in the `Set` for the life of the object.

What is the proper way to do this in C++? Should the `string` just be allocated on the heap through `new` and then destroyed manually?

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    private:
        set<string> myStrings;
        
    public:
        void DoSomething(string s);
}

Foo::DoSomething(string s)
{
    myStrings.insert(s);
} // s would be destroyed here?
```

Comment: Yes `s` would be destroyed but it would remain inside the `set` as a copy for the lifetime of the whole set itself. (Since the set is inside the class, that means all the strings will be destroyed when the class's destructor is called.)

Comment: Do you mean that calling myStrings.insert creates a copy of s which is placed in the set?

Comment: Yes, by default, almost every container in C++ takes its argument by copy and so does `set`.

Comment: Whay you have is correct. Why are you worried about the destruction of the strings? You have a copy of them inserted into the set, and because the set doesn't allow duplicates you would not be able to keep the original alive in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that in C++ string objects have their destructors called as soon as they leave scope. So if I understand correctly, when the calling method which created the string exits scope, the destructor should be called.

Yes, your understanding here is correct. But, in case of this line here:

```cpp
myStrings.insert(s);
```

<sup>From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert):</sup>

This overload of `std::set::insert` has the following signature:

```cpp
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
```

What this function does is that it simply takes `value` by **value**, not by **reference**.

Since the function only takes its argument by value and does not care about where it exists in the memory, it just takes whatever values your string had and creates a new copy of it (with a new address, completely unrelated to `s`) to be placed inside `myStrings`

Hypothetically, if `std::set::insert` took its parameter as an lvalue (i.e, `&` instead of `const &`), then it would have ended up like what you had expected, `s`'s address would be directly placed inside of `myStrings` and no copies would be created, but after `s`'s destructor gets called, the reference becomes invalidated if you try to use it, the program's behavior becomes undefined.

Comment: OP uses `std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );` overload, and there are no UB. `std::set` does a copy of the `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I want the string to live in the Set for the life of the object.

The string will live in the `set` for the lifetime of the object. This is because even though the original string passed to the function `Foo::DoSomething(string s)` is destroyed at the end of scope, the string is *copied* into the container.

> What is the proper way to do this in C++?

The way you have done is completely fine. If you want to avoid the copy for performance reasons, you can use move semantics. Example:

```cpp
Foo::DoSomething(string s)
{
    myStrings.insert(std::move(s)); // resources of 's' are moved into the set.
    //...                           // s is empty now, but valid
} // s is destroyed here
```

You can do the following experiment to verify this:

```
int main()
{
    set<string> s;
    { // scope start
        /* create new strings */
        string s1 = "hello";
        string s2 = "123";
        string s3 = "abc";

        /* insert them into set*/
        s.insert(s1);
        s.insert(s2);
        s.insert(std::move(s3)); //move s3
        
        cout << "s3 contains: " << s3 << endl; //check value of s3

      // s1, s2, s3 will be destroyed now
    } // scope end
    
    //print all the strings inside the est
    for (const auto str : s) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But be aware, move semantics has a lot of tricky details, and sometimes you might be thinking that you are moving, but in reality it is just a copy, e.g, moving from a `const` object. So be sure to read up on it to discover the details :)